Do I *Always* Need to Access GUI Elements from External Threads Using Signal/Slot in PyQt5?
While developing a Windows-based program using PyQt5, I encountered issues where the GUI was not updating in a timely manner due to long computation or wait times. To resolve this, I moved some computations to multiple threads.
These computations included not only methods that directly modify GUI elements, such as setText, setEnabled, and textBrowser.append, but also methods that retrieve the state of GUI elements, like isChecked() and text().
Although the program ran without any errors, ChatGPT advised me that directly controlling GUI elements from threads other than the main thread could cause problems. As a result, I started converting all these methods to use signal/slot mechanisms. Consequently, the following additional dumb code was added to the MyWindow class, making it quite annoying to handle:
to_textBrowser = pyqtSignal(str)
to_textBrowser_2 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_textBrowser_3 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_statusBar = pyqtSignal(str)
clear_textBrowser = pyqtSignal()
clear_textBrowser_2 = pyqtSignal()

to_lineEdit_10 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_lineEdit_12 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_lineEdit_14 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_lineEdit_16 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_lineEdit_18 = pyqtSignal(str)
to_lineEdit_20 = pyqtSignal(str)

to_label_text = pyqtSignal(QObject, str)
guest_backup_dialog_signal = pyqtSignal()
accountbook_dialog_signal = pyqtSignal()
show_popup_signal = pyqtSignal()

set_enable = pyqtSignal(QObject, bool)
set_check = pyqtSignal(QObject, bool)
set_exclusive = pyqtSignal(QObject, bool)
get_check = pyqtSignal(QObject)
get_text = pyqtSignal(QObject)



def __init__(self):
  self.to_label_text.connect(lambda label, text: label.setText(text))
  self.set_enable.connect(lambda obj, bool: obj.setEnabled(bool))
  self.set_check.connect(lambda obj, bool: obj.setChecked(bool))
  self.set_exclusive.connect(lambda obj, bool: obj.setExclusive(bool))

  self.to_textBrowser.connect(lambda text : (self.textBrowser.append(text),     trading_history_q.put(text)))
  self.to_textBrowser_2.connect(lambda text : (self.textBrowser_2.append(text), trading_history_q.put(text)))
  self.to_textBrowser_3.connect(lambda text : (self.textBrowser_3.append(text), trading_history_q.put(text)))
  self.to_statusBar.connect(lambda text : self.statusBar().showMessage(text))
  self.clear_textBrowser.connect(lambda : self.textBrowser.clear())
  self.clear_textBrowser_2.connect(lambda : self.textBrowser_2.clear())

  self.to_lineEdit_10.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_10.setText(text))
  self.to_lineEdit_12.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_12.setText(text))
  self.to_lineEdit_14.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_14.setText(text))
  self.to_lineEdit_16.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_16.setText(text))
  self.to_lineEdit_18.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_18.setText(text))
  self.to_lineEdit_20.connect(lambda text : self.lineEdit_20.setText(text))

  self.get_check_value = None
  def get_check_(object_):
      self.get_check_value = object_.isChecked()        
  self.get_check.connect(get_check_)

  self.get_text_value = None
  def get_text_(object_):
      self.get_check_value = object_.text()  
  self.get_text.connect(get_text_)

Is this really necessary? Even if it is required, do methods that merely read the current state of GUI elements, such as isChecked() and text(), also need to be implemented using the signal/slot mechanism?
Despite taking these precautions, I have never encountered any specific issues or errors related to direct access to GUI elements from threads other than the main thread. This makes me wonder if my efforts were unnecessary.

This is one of the few cases for which a proper suggestion was given by a gen AI. But  you shouldn't rely on them to begin with, unless you're experienced enough. 1. Yes, UI elements are not thread-safe, and must always be accessed only through signals connected to functions that manipulate them in their thread; 2. The fact that the program runs without errors is "sheer dumb luck" [cit.]: unsafe doesn't mean "forbidden", but "dangerously unreliable and with unknown results"; it may work without debug errors on your system and with your current code, but it's destined to fail sooner or »

» later, and completely unexpectedly, in ways difficult to reproduce (and debug) and with issues like unexpected behavior, graphical artifacts or even fatal program crash; 3. Yes, it's necessary, but your approach is poorly implemented: it's "annoying to handle" because you made it so (and your unnecessary use of lambdas doesn't help). For instance, instead of using separated signals for every "target widget", you could just use one signal with a further argument that indicates the target (eg. using an index); 3. read access is normally safer, but it's also unreliable (the thread will read »

» that value when it can, instead of getting it when required to, which calls for access issues in case the object that has to be read may be destroyed in the meantime) and similarly unsafe, since, in order to return their values, some getters need to create temporary objects that should not be created in separate threads. So: your efforts were not unnecessary, just misplaced and wrongly implemented. Finally, it seems you're trying to implement threading within the same widget class (possibly using Thread). While acceptable/reasonable under certain circumstances, it's normally discouraged »

» if this usage increases the implementation in that single class: you should create at least one separate class for the thread instead (possibly based on a QObject moved to a QThread, or by directly subclassing QThread) with its own signals. While this may apparently increase complexity, it will also make code much cleaner and easier to handle. Note that I won't provide an answer for this, as your code has too many issues and implicit/unexplained aspects, while, generally speaking (on the Qt/thread subjects) there already are enough related posts here on SO, which I suggest you to look up.
